# Fast AdHoc Queries

Tags: sql, key-value, adhoc, columnstore

- (Requirements)
- We need a **fast** and **scalable** solution.
- We need faster way of doing adhoc queries;

I am thinking about seperating my 10 column table into 10 tables.
The table has got 10 Billion rows.

Original Table
ID,VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3,VALUE4,VALUE5,VALUE6,VALUE7,VALUE8,VALUE9,VALUE10

into 10 tables

- ID,VALUE1 (indexed on value1)
- ID,VALUE2 (indexed on value2)
- ID,VALUE3 (indexed on value3)
- ID,VALUE4 (indexed on value4)
- ID,VALUE5 (indexed on value5)
- ID,VALUE6 (indexed on value6)
- ID,VALUE7 (indexed on value7)
- ID,VALUE8 (indexed on value8)
- ID,VALUE9 (indexed on value9)
- ID,VALUE10 (indexed on value10)

My plan is if i got a 5 clauses in my WHERE condition , go to 5 tables and asked them than use a hashset to set a subset of ID's.

My Question is  i am reinventing the wheel ?is this  ["Column Store DB By RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS)" or something else?

Comment: What database software are you using?

Comment: What do your queries look like?  What is the frequency of each of the values?  What is the selectivity (how many rows are selected) of a typical query?  How frequently is the data updated?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 10 tables. 1 table with 10 indexes will have the same result.
For the performance it depends on the clause. If your where clause is an AND expression like

```
select * from table 
where value1 = x
and value3 = y
```

then splitting the query won't help.

If your where clause is an OR expression like

```
select * from table 
where value1 = x
or value3 = y
or value5 = z
```

then *maybe* rephrasing the one query to a union would be faster.

```
select * from table 
where value1 = x
union select * from table 
where value3 = y
union select * from table 
where value5 = z
```

But performance always depends on the database engine, and its optimizer.

Comment: 1 table with 10 indexes will have the same result.I supposed to scale that without losing performance. More indexes on same table means less performance.Like 10 girlfriends living in the same neighbourhood.Things get messed up so easily.I like them to be in seperate cities.:) I would like to be able to distribute the load to  a cluster.

Comment: Why do you think that 10 tables could be better performing than one table with 10 indexes? 10 tables, means that for 1 row you need to insert to 10 tables. 1 insert should be faster than 10. The load can be distributed to a cluster, but the application shouldn't be affected from that. This should be taken over by the database clustering layer.

Comment: The load can be distributed to a cluster, but the application shouldn't be affected from that. >>> thats the reason.